# How many paths are there from point P to point Q if each step has to go closer to point Q.

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

[image]Each of the six faces of a solid cube is divided into four squares as indicated in the diagram. Starting from vertex P paths can be travelled to vertex Q along connected line segments. Each movement along a path must take one closer to Q. How many possible paths are there from P to Q?

I got 96 different routes. I found 48 in these three sides shown and then multiplied by 2 to count for the other sides. Not sure if I am correct. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

Every path from $P$ to $Q$ consists of two steps forward, two steps down, and two steps to the left. The question becomes: In how many ways  can we permute the string "FFDDLL"? The answer is
$$
\frac{6!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!} = 90
$$

Edit: Thanks to LotharNarins. This doesn't account for the fact that you can't go through the center. This happens exactly when the first three letters are all distinct, i.e. a permutation of "FDL". Because you need 3 steps to get to the center, and if two of the first three letters are the same, you've already gone past it.

There are $3!$ ways to arrange the letters "FDL". For each of these there are $3!$ ways to arrange the remaining 3 letters, so the final answer is
$$
90-3!\cdot 3! = 54.
$$

Comment: Have you taken into account the points at which stepping to the left does not bring you closer to $Q$? I thought we had to rule those cases out. I get an answer of 36, but I suspect I'm somehow wrong.

Comment: @MattS When would stepping to the left not bring you closer to $Q$?

Comment: If you go "down" on your first step, you only have an option to go either "forward" or "down", not to the left, right? Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: I'm trying to say that anything starting with DL would perhaps not be a valid permutation?

Comment: Why can't I go to the left after going down? "Each of the six faces of a solid cube is divided into four squares", meaning there are lines even on the faces you can't see.

Comment: Rats. I misunderstood the question. Not your answer. Sorry!

Comment: Some of these paths (for instance FDLFDL) take you into the center of the cube, which I think is not allowed. You should subtract the $3! \cdot 3! = 36$ paths going through the center, to get an answer of $54$.

Comment: @LotharNarins You're right, thanks! But I think there are only $3!$ ways to get to the center.

Comment: But there are $3!$ ways to get back out for each of those ways.

Comment: @LotharNarins Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There's an algorithm for answering problems like this. Label your initial point 1, since there's 1 path to reach the starting point from the starting point. As the inductive step, label any unlabeled vertex adjacent to a labelled vertex with the sum of all adjacent labelled vertices. Since your graph has (an upper bound of) $9 \cdot 6 = 54$ vertices, this may take a little time, but should not prove challenging.

Comment: There's only 26 possible locations here, and there's 3-fold symmetry, so it wouldn't be that bad at all to bash out.